# If $a,b,c>0$ and $a^3+b^3=c^3$ then prove that $a^2+b^2-c^2>6(c-a)(c-b)$.

Tags: inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

If $a,b,c>0$ and $a^3+b^3=c^3$ then prove that $$a^2+b^2-c^2>6(c-a)(c-b)$$.

I tried factoring but things got more complicated. I dont think standard AM-Gm can be applied directly. Can somebody help me to proceed? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to prove that 
$$c(a^2+b^2)-(a^3+b^3)>6c(c-a)(c-b)$$ or
$$\frac{(c^3-b^3)(c-a)}{a}+\frac{(c^3-a^3)(c-b)}{b}>6c(c-a)(c-b)$$ or
$$\frac{b^2+bc+c^2}{a}+\frac{a^2+ac+c^2}{b}>6c$$
which is AM-GM.

Done!